# Generate hash to match the User password

Tags: shell, centos, centos7

On CentOS 7, I'm trying to create a shell script which will be executed by PHP that will allow me to login using CentOS User.

Below is the Hash password that I got from `/etc/shadow`

```
root:$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$.srI2tX1NXWpO0PSqaoB06hi0mvJ59Z3G4VpzT.3481gLNVvO6EPpsIaUkB5E/m8EZvMKXui.5GySJJ618.H8.::0:99999:7:::
```

This is the breakdown

```
Algorithm: sha512
Salt: LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/
hash: .srI2tX1NXWpO0PSqaoB06hi0mvJ59Z3G4VpzT.3481gLNVvO6EPpsIaUkB5E/m8EZvMKXui.5GySJJ618.H8.
```

How would I generate a password that will match the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python 3 and greater to generate the hash password.

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$RandomSalt/$")'
```

Change `MyPassword` to your plain text password and `$RandomSalt` to the salt you have.

By running the above you will get something like

```
.srI2tX1NXWpO0PSqaoB06hi0mvJ59Z3G4VpzT.3481gLNVvO6EPpsIaUkB5E/m8EZvMKXui.5GySJJ618.H8.
```

Now you can glue them together using `$` so it will become

```
$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$.srI2tX1NXWpO0PSqaoB06hi0mvJ59Z3G4VpzT.3481gLNVvO6EPpsIaUkB5E/m8EZvMKXui.5GySJJ618.H8.
```